# Condition necessary and sufficient in order a function to be periodic

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, periodic-functions

Let $f:  \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Consider the following properties:

$(1)$ $\;$ $f$ is a periodic function, with (minimal) period $a>0$;

$(2)$ $\;$ $f(0)=f(a)=0$ and $f'(a)=f'(0)=0$.

**Question.** Is true that $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$?

Note that $(1) \Rightarrow (2)$. Indeed, since by definition of periodic function,
$$
f(x)=f(x+a) \Rightarrow f'(x)=f'(x+a), \; \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
we have, in particular for $x=0$, $f(0)=f(a)$ and $f'(a)=f'(0)$.

And the converse, is true? It's possible to use the fact that every periodic function is bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(2) \implies (1)$ is not always true. Take
$$f(x)=x^2(x-1)^2$$

it is easy to check that

$ f $ is differentiable,

$$f(0)=f(1)=0,$$
and

$$f'(0)=f'(1)=0$$

but, clearly, $ f $ is not periodic :
$$f(2+1)=36\ne f(2)$$

Comment: Do you know if there exists some condition necessary and sufficient in order a function to be periodic?

Comment: $ f $ is a-periodic $\iff f' $ is a-periodic and $ f(0)=f(a)$